# Handle different onPress functions TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile-application

I am developing a mobile app using React Native with Expo CLI and TypeScript.

I have a screen in my app that contains two cards and two buttons inside those cards.
To develop the cards, I did a reusable component so that I don't repeat code.

The code for this reusable component is this:

```
export function AccountCards(props: any = {}) {
  const { header, content, text, style, handler } = props;
  return (
    <Card
      mode="elevated"
      elevation={5}
      style={[styles.cardPoints, styles.cards, style]}
    >
      <Card.Content>
        <Title style={styles.cardTitle}>{header}</Title>
        <Paragraph style={styles.cardText}>{content}</Paragraph>
      </Card.Content>
      <Card.Actions>
        <Button
          mode="contained"
          style={styles.cardBtn}
          onPress={handler}
          labelStyle={{ color: colors.buttonTextColor }}
        >
          {text}
        </Button>
      </Card.Actions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

This component is used in a screen then. The code is:

```
export function AccountScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Olá, Utilizador</Text>
      <AccountCards
        header={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardPoints.title}
        content={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardPoints.content}
        text={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardPoints.pointsButton}
        style={{
          marginBottom: 30,
        }}
        handler={PointsScreen}
      />
      <AccountCards
        header={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardHistory.title}
        content={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardHistory.content}
        text={strings.screens.accountScreen.cardHistory.historyButton}
      />
      <Button mode="contained" style={styles.editBtn}>
        {strings.screens.accountScreen.editProfileButton}
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This code doesn't seems to work, I guess I didn't pass the onPress prop correctly.

I also tried to pass it as an arrow function but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is `PointsScreen`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm sorry, I forgot to mention but ```PointsScreen``` is the screen that I want when the user clicks the button

Comment: You didn't provide the `handler` prop to `AccountCards` where you use it twice.

Comment: Isn't `onPress` an event handling callback function? You're passing it a component which, while indeed a function, is unlikely to do what you want unless the body of that component function is very unusual.

Comment: What I want is to have different screens to those buttons, like when a user presses the first button, it goes to ```PointsScreen``` and when he presses the second one it goes to another screen

Comment: In that case you need to add navigation first. Check it out here - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

After that you can use navigation object and navigate to the selected screen. 
Example:
handler={()=>navigation.navigate("PointsScreen")}